# Problem with plugin chartjs-plugin-zoom in chartJS

Tags: javascript, php, html, model-view-controller, chart.js

I am creating a MCV type website where I am implementing a bar graph with the ChartJS library. The problem is that I'm trying to implement the chartjs-plugin-zoom plugin to be able to zoom within the chart itself.

I have checked the libraries so that it is not a version problem but it still does not work. I also tried it inside another simpler graph; if it works, then I don't know what could be wrong.

This is the code part of the view:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <form action="" method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select id="valores_sel" class="custom-select">
                        <option value="">Feature Type Select</option>
                        <script>
                            var data = csv_data[date];
                            var usedNames = [];
                            var options = '';
                            for (var i = 0; i < featureTypeNames.length; i++) {
                                var names = featureTypeNames[i];
                                for (j = 0; j < dates.length; j++) {
                                    if (!usedNames.includes(names)) {
                                        usedNames.push(names);
                                        for (var featureType in data) {
                                            if (names == featureType) {
                                                var featureType_values = (data[featureType]);
                                                featureType_values = Object.keys(featureType_values);
                                                options += `<option value='${featureType_values}'>${names}</option>`;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                };
                            };
                            document.getElementById("valores_sel").innerHTML += options;
                        </script>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <canvas id="myChart" width="850" height="254" box-sizing="border-box" display="block" style="box-sizing: border-box; "></canvas>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <script>
            const ct = document.getElementById('myChart');
            const barChart = new Chart(ct, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: {
                    labels: finalDates.map(date => new Date(date)),
                    datasets: datasets_
                },
                options: {
                    plugins: {
                        zoom: {
                            zoom: {
                            wheel: {
                                enabled: true,
                            },
                            pinch: {
                                enabled: true
                            },
                            mode: 'xy',
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    responsive: true,
                    scales: {
                        x: {
                            type: 'time',
                            time: {
                                unit: 'year'
                            },
                            stacked: true
                        },
                        y: {
                            type: 'logarithmic',
                            position: 'right',
                            stacked: true,
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            const valores_sel = document.getElementById('valores_sel');
            valores_sel.addEventListener('change', valores_selector);

            function valores_selector() {
                var datos_finales = valores_sel.value.split(',');
                var count = datos_finales.length;
                var labels_finales = [];
                for (var j = 0; j < count; j++) {
                    labels_finales.push(datos_finales[j])
                }

                var datasets_ = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < labels_finales.length; i++) {
                    var label = labels_finales[i];
                    var valores_finales = [];

                    for (var j = 0; j < arrayGrande.length; j++) {
                        var item = arrayGrande[j];
                        if (label in item) {
                            valores_finales = item[label];
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    // Verificar si la característica ya tiene un color asignado en colorMap
                    if (!colorMap[label]) {
                        // Generar un nuevo color aleatorio y asignarlo a la característica
                        colorMap[label] = getRandomColor();
                    }

                    // Crear el dataset con los datos y color correspondientes
                    var dataset = {
                        label: label,
                        data: valores_finales,
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        backgroundColor: colorMap[label]
                    };
                    datasets_.push(dataset);
                }
                // Actualizar los datasets del gráfico y actualizar el gráfico
                barChart.data.datasets = datasets_;
                barChart.update();

            }
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

```